# Does Docker automate IP masquerade rules in iptables for bridge networks?

Tags: networking, docker, iptables, qnap

I have `docker-1.9.1` running on a QNAP raid machine. It has the default `bridge` network using subnet `10.0.3.0/24`. In iptables I see a rule in the `nat` table:

`-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`

I am assuming that Docker created this rule itself.

I have created a new bridge network:

```
docker network create \
--gateway=10.0.5.1 \
--subnet=10.0.5.0/24 \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="0.0.0.0" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc"="true" \
-o "com.docker.network.driver.mtu"="1500" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="lxcbr1" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade"="true" \
isolated_nw
```

This does not create a rule in iptables. Did I miss a step?

Here's the full setup commands and results, copying @larsks' example:

```
[/share/Containers] # docker --version
Docker version 1.9.1, build 147ce3e
[/share/Containers] # iptables -t nat -S | grep 10.0.5.0
[/share/Containers] # docker network create \
> --gateway=10.0.5.1 \
> --subnet=10.0.5.0/24 \
> -o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="0.0.0.0" \
> -o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc"="true" \
> -o "com.docker.network.driver.mtu"="1500" \
> -o "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="lxcbr1" \
> -o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade"="true" \
> isolated_nw
a7b5c938008169f32fcdfc1d9409716b725cc916b30f472ac6ec2a1d71fb77f0
[/share/Containers] # iptables -t nat -S | grep 10.0.5.0
[/share/Containers] # iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
[/share/Containers] #
```

Comment: Are you aware of 'Create your own bridge network' at  https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/networkingcontainers/ ?

Comment: I used examples on that page to create my own network. Doesn't look like it covers ip masquerade or iptables.

Comment: It...actually does.  You can see the actual sequence of commands I ran in my answer.  Or you can watch this, which is an actual session of me running the same tests: https://asciinema.org/a/9ipp0n6izkcb3iqk2tdgmpx1i

Comment: I meant the documentation doesn't cover ip masquerade, other than the configuration option `com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade`. On my QNAP machine, Docker isn't creating the iptables rules properly for user-created networks, as seen in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Docker 1.9.1 (on Fedora 23 Atomic), and your command seems to work just fine.

Before creating the network:

```
# docker --version
Docker version 1.9.1, build 7206621
# iptables -t nat -S | grep 10.0.5.0
<no result>
```

Create the network:

```
docker network create \
--gateway=10.0.5.1 \
--subnet=10.0.5.0/24 \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="0.0.0.0" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc"="true" \
-o "com.docker.network.driver.mtu"="1500" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="lxcbr1" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade"="true" \
isolated_nw
```

Check iptables:

```
# iptables -t nat -S | grep 10.0.5.0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.5.0/24 ! -o lxcbr1 -j MASQUERADE
```

...I note that running `docker network rm isolated_nw`, while it correctly deletes the bridge device, does not seem to remove the iptables rule.  This seems to be fixed in more recent versions of Docker (e.g., I'm running 1.11.0 locally, and that version seems to correctly remove the rule on network delete).

**Update**

If that update to your question has the entire output from `iptables -t nat -S`, then something else is going on, because you are missing the `DOCKER` chain in the `nat` table.

```
# iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.5.0/24 ! -o lxcbr1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And in fact, I'm surprised that your `create network` command even completes, because if I manually remove the `DOCKER` chain and references, attempts to create a new network on my system result in:

```
Error response from daemon: Failed to program NAT chain: Failed to 
inject docker in PREROUTING chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait
-t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER: iptables 
v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `DOCKER':No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm amending my question with my version of these commands. Doesn't create the rule and still not sure why.

Comment: I have a docker chain, but not in the `nat` table.

    [/share/Containers] # iptables -S
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -N DOCKER